# Set default implementation in Castle Windsor 2.5 (for decorators)

Tags: castle-windsor, decorator

I'm working with Castle Windsor 2.5 (upgrading is not currently an option), and am trying to register decorators after the original components have been registered. It seems that in castle version 3 you can use IsDefault to achieve this. Is there a similar operation in castle 2.5 or else some other way to achieve this?

Just to be clear, I cannot change the registration order so that decorators are registered first. This is a platform architecture in which the default platform behavior can be modified by customers by adding to or changing existing registrations.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like IHandlerSelector does the trick:

```
public class DecoratorHandler : IHandlerSelector
{
    private readonly IWindsorContainer _container;
    private readonly HashSet<Type> _decoratedTypes = new HashSet<Type>();

    public DecoratorHandler(IWindsorContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    public bool HasOpinionAbout(string key, Type service)
    {
        return _decoratedTypes.Contains(service);
    }

    public IHandler SelectHandler(string key, Type service, IHandler[] handlers)
    {
        return handlers[handlers.Length - 1];
    }

    public void Register<TTarget, TDecorator>() where TDecorator : TTarget, IDecorator<TTarget>
    {
        _container.Register(Component.For<TTarget>().ImplementedBy<TDecorator>());
        _decoratedTypes.Add(typeof(TTarget));
    }
}
```

And

```
_decoratorHandler = new DecoratorHandler(_container);
_container.Kernel.AddHandlerSelector(_decoratorHandler);
```